# Converting Byte[] to String - Interbase to C# - InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, string, arrays, blob, oledbdatareader

I'm using `OleDbDataReader rdr` to read a "Comments" field in BLOB form (sub_type 1 segment size 80) into a string from an Interbase DB, and I keep getting exceptions. Any suggestions?

**Attempt #1**

```
ls_Chap_Comments.Add((rdr["Comments"]).ToString());
```

InvalidCastException: The data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow. For example, the data was corrupted in the data store but the row was still retrievable."

**Attempt #2**

```
byte[] b = new byte[100];
b = (byte[])rdr["Comments"];
string s = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
```

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `System.String` to type `System.Byte[]`

**Attempt #3**

```
// 17 is the BLOB column zero-based location for "Comments"
retval = rdr.GetBytes(17, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
```

InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `System.String` to type `System.Byte[]`.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried just casting the value to a string - as in it already was converted to a string for you?

Comment: Yes, that was my first attempt.
Trying `ls_Chap_Comments.Add((string)(rdr["Comments"]));` gives me 
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type `System.DBNull` to type `System.String`

Comment: Have you tried putting a breakpoint, then putting a watch for `rdr["Comments"].GetType()` to see what type it actually is?

Comment: Ah, you should do a check before casting => `if (b==DBNull.Value)`

Comment: Hmm... `rdr["Comments"].GetType()` is string... 
Thing is, all the other columns I'm getting from the DB are strings, and it's only this one (which is a BLOB) that is giving me trouble.

Comment: That's because when there is a null value read from the database, the reader returns `DBNull.Value` rather than anything of type `byte[]` or `string`. You must check it before doing any casting because `DBNull.Value` is not a `byte[]` nor `string`.

Comment: Incidentally, removing the explicit casting to string with `ls_Chap_Comments.Add(rdr["Comments"]);` gives me: "Cannot convert object to string"

Comment: `if ((rdr["Comments"]) == DBNull.Value)` gives me the same InvalidCastException as Attempt #1

Comment: I've added an answer that should address your problem. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

```
rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("Comments"))
```

before trying to read the value.

Comment: Unfortunately, `if (!rdr.IsDBNull(17)) { ls_Chap_Comments.Add("Something"); }
else { ls_Chap_Comments.Add((rdr["Comments"]).ToString()); }` yields "Something" in the response... Which means it's not DBNull...

Comment: Shouldn't `!rdr.IsDBNull(17)` be `rdr.IsDBNull(17)`

Comment: Running it as `if (rdr.IsDBNull(17)) { ls_Chap_Comments.Add("Something"); } else { ls_Chap_Comments.Add((rdr["Comments"]).ToString()); }` gives me the same error as Attempt #1

Comment: 17 is the 18th column in the select statement, right?

`Select ct.call_id, ct.operator, ct.call_datetime,                                               ci.last_name, ci.first_name, ci.prefix, ci.prisoner_no,                                                ci.address_1, ci.address_2, ci.male_female,                                                ci.city, ci.state, ci.postal_zip, ci.zip_plus_4,                                               ci.phone_number, ci.email,                                                chap_t.chap_type, chap_t.comments`

Comment: `rdr.GetOrdinal("Comments")` gives me 17

Comment: Thanks for your help @armen.shimoon, I'll take another look at this either tomorrow or Monday

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this, but it is less difficult than it seems.
Retrieve the value as an object type and cast it to string (assuming the blob contains a string).

```
string commentsValue = (string)rdr.GetValue(17);
```